# Given base and n that are both 1 or more, compute recursively (no loops) the value of base to the n power, so powerN(3, 2) is 9 (3 squared). in java

Tags: java

```
public static void powerNum(int n,int x,int t) {
    int i = 1;
    if(x>i){
       i++;         
       powerNum(n,x,t);
    }
    else{ 
       System.out.println(n); 
    }
}
```

this is what I have done so far. I think its correct but I keep  getting the  stack overflow error, and remember. it must be recursive!!! full answers please.

Comment: HINTS: `x**y = x * (x**(y-1))` and `x**1 = x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static int powerNum(int n, int x) {
    if(x == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return n* powerNum(n, x-1);
    }
}
```

I think this block is what you are looking for?

Comment: it isn't printing it

Comment: `System.out.println(powerNum(2,3))` like this?

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing `i` to the next function call and you always initialize `i` to `1`, so the condition `if(x>i)` is always true, provided `x` is more than one. In the `if` you have a recursive call:

```
if(x>i){
   i++;         
   powerNum(n,x,t);
}
```

This results in infinite recursion. Also you never change or use the values of `n`, `x` or `t`.

Here is some psuedocode to help you:

```
accept three parameters: base, power, and result
if the power less than one
   print the result
else 
   multiply the result by the base
   recursive call passing base, power-1, and result
```

The only thing about this is that `result` always needs to be passed as one, which is rather inconvenient. You could create an overloaded function to only accept the base and power, and then call the original `powerNum` function, passing `1` as the result:

```
public static void powerNum(int base, int power) {
    powerNum(base, power, 1);
}
```

Comment: or even use the values of `n` or `t`

Comment: public static void powerNum(int n,int x,int t,int i) {
  
     if(n>i){
        i++;         
    x=x*t;
        powerNum(n,x,t,i);
     }
     else{ 
    }
   System.out.println(n);
  
 }

Comment: it will give me 2 not 9

Comment: @helpme *if the power less than one* - how does that equate to `if(n>i)` ? and where is `power-1`

Comment: @helpme You don't need to pass four parameters. Also you are mixing up which variables represent what. I suggest using more descriptive variable names than `x`, `n` and `t`

Comment: Results cannot be communicated back through arguments.  The method signature should be `public static int powerNum(int n, int x)`

Comment: @KevinAnderson The OP wants the method to be `void`

Comment: As I read the question, the only _requirement_ was to compute a power..  But if it really does have to be a `void` method, there'll need to be some other mechanism to transmit partial results back:  either `static` member variables (ugh!) or through some mutable object passed as an argument (also ugh!).  So much simpler to return the partial result as a function value.